# Edit restriction for too-few characters improperly applied

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

You are allowed to edit even a single character in the title of a question. I recently did this (without edit privileges) for a question that had a confusing (yet obvious after reading the question) typo in the title.

While I was there, I figured I'd capitalize the first letter of a sentence in the question body that wasn't capitalized.

The problem is that this edit was rejected for being too few characters. The cure was to start over, re-edit the post's title, and then edit even *fewer* characters in the question body: 0.

This makes no sense to me. If a one-letter edit to a question title with no edits to the question itself is allowed, then shouldn't such a title edit with a few characters changed in the question also be allowed?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe ten title edits don't make a question become community wiki, while ten body edits do.

Comment: We're discussing this - here's the [canonical bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79342/title-edit-plus-minor-body-edit-return-too-short-error) on Meta Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130741/89334, this has been completed. This answer is here so that this question will no longer appear on the Unanswered list once it has been upvoted/accepted.